# Adding Image into Webpage using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why does my image show up as a file logo? link below

[This is how my image shows up when I add it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivC2p.png)

This is my JS for the image (AngularJS)

```javascript
{
    name: 'Screw',
    price: 1,
    description: 'A small item drilled into objects',
    specs: '1 centimeter',
    images: [
                {
                    full: "1024px-Phillips_screw.jpg"
                }
            ]
}
```

This is my HTML for adding the image

```html
<img ng-src="{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
```

Comment: what is the path of the image? check the path. its just a image name

Comment: Provided Link is broken

Comment: Check your image full path and compare it with `ng-src` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [ng-src directive](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-src.asp)? *ie.*

```
<div ng-init="myVar='pic_angular.jpg'">
    <h1>Angular</h1>
    <img ng-src="{{myVar}}">
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do this.  If you use plain `src` you will get an extra network call as the browser tries to load the un-interpolated text given in the `src` and then fire **another** network request when the text gets interpolated.

Comment: You learn something new every day. Thanks @zero298, your answer makes a lot more sense than mine, good stuff!

Comment: ok, but if i have multiple images in an array in my app.js file, how would i use a directive in html then? im a bit slow today, sorry about that.

Comment: pass them through variables like within the example above

Answer (score 2):

Check the console for the error, but it's probably because the path is incorrect.

If they're in your images folder you'd want to put that path:

```
<img src="/images/{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
```

Comment: This is the incorrect way to do this.  Per my comment on swordfish's answer: If you use plain `src` you will get an extra network call as the browser tries to load the un-interpolated text given in the `src` and then fire **another** network request when the text gets interpolated.

Comment: @zero298 is right. Thanks for help though William Hampshire

Comment: Sure thing @TheWorldSoul. Didn't even occur to me to do it the way swordfish proposed. That's why I love this place!

Answer (score 0):

Its passing only name of image into ng-src, you need to write whole path of image where it saved before u pass image name into curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use absolute or relative path for the image, like

```
<img src="/images/{{product.images[0].full}}"/>
```

If you use the latest angularjs 4.x with cli, you need to add the images path to "assets" section in angular-cli.json:

"apps": [
    {
      ......

```
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    "images"
  ],
  ........
```

}

Comment: yeah ill use file path, thanks @Blockchain Nerd. Not that comfortable with Ang4 yet haha